# Use of uninitialized value $1 in RegEx

Tags: regex, perl

I have this code:

```
foreach my $line(<INFILE>) {
  @data = split('\t', $line);
  print OUTNC "$1\n" if ($data[1] =~ /NC_/);
}
```

But when I run it, it gaves me the next error:
"Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at parser.pl line 15,  line 190805."

Can you tell what's the error? Thanks!!

Comment: You have no `(...)` in your regex.

Comment: `'\t'` in single quotes is literally the backslash character and the letter "t". You probably meant to use double quotes (`"\t"`) or regex delimiters (`/\t/`)

Comment: something like this?
/NC_.{8}/
or?
/NC_......../

Comment: `/(NC_.{0,8})/`? Without `()`, you won't have `$1` initialized.